# Is there a way to use TaskContinuationOptions like a finally

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, continuewith

Is there a way to use TaskContinuationOptions like a finally?

Here is my code

```
        ShowLoading();
        Task.Factory.StartNew((Action)(() =>
        {
            _broker.SetDrugDataFromAPI(newDrug);

        })).ContinueWith(x => 
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                //Do Something to UI
            }
        }, _uiScheduler).ContinueWith(x =>
        {
            //Do Somehting after change UI
        }).ContinueWith(x =>
        {
            HideLoading();
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

Here is my question

I wanted to use last ContinueWith like a finally.
So, I changed my last ContinueWith phrase like this

```
        }).ContinueWith(x =>
        {
            HideLoading();
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion | 
           TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

I thought it be used when the last task is complete or fault.

But It throws a error.

I hope there is a good way to solve my problem.

thank you for reading my question.

Comment: Wich error is thrown? And why do you not just use a finally block in the task?

Comment: Thank you for comment.
There is a for phrase in the ContinueWith phrase.
When I use for phase in a task, I can't synchronize tasks.
It goes into outside of task when task go into a for phase in a task.
So, I can't use try finally phase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify a `TaskContinuationOptions` then it will run in all states - whether the `Task` is faulted (Exception), cancelled, or completed successfully.

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            var task = Task.CompletedTask
            .ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("Run after completed"))
            .ContinueWith(t => throw new Exception("Blow up"))
            .ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("Run after exception"))
            .ContinueWith(t => cts.Cancel())
            .ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("This will never be hit because we have been cancelled"), cts.Token)
            .ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("Run after cancelled."));

            await task;
        }
    }
}
```

This program produces the following output:

```
Run after completed
Run after exception
Run after cancelled.
```